# Integrating Custom build of clang-tidy in CodeChecker

Tags: linker, llvm, static-analysis, clang-tidy

I successfully installed CodeChecker (https://codechecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#install-guide). The check and analyze commands that CodeChecker provided work on my input files.
Now, my task is to integrate checkers that I want to run on the input inside CodeChecker. I understood that there's way to do this by registering the checker inside clang-tidy. This has been done successfully. However, I'm stuck with integrating my custom build clang-tidy inside CodeChecker.

The documentation suggests that we have to change package_layout.json inside config folder (https://codechecker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/analyzer/user_guide/#configuring-clang-version). This has been done and I also set the `CC_ANALYZERS_FROM_PATH`to 1 using command `export CC_ANALYZERS_FROM_PATH=1`. Even after the changes the changes that I made to clang-tidy are not getting reflected and the checkers are not available. I strongly suspect that CodeChecker is still not accessing my custom clang-tidy build and taking the one that's installed.

Can someone give me ideas about how to triage this problem?